Select query appearing to not use the most appropriate index
I have a table with approximately 80 columns. Several of these are indexed. These include age, shoesize and height - all are integers.
I then have a query that I am trying to optimise:
select * from people where age > 18 and shoesize > 10 and height > 150

To try and speed the query up I have created a new combined index of the three columns in question - age, shoesize and height. I have called this index combinedIndex
If I then run:
explain select * from people where age > 18 and shoesize > 10 and height > 150

Then I see this output:
id = 1
select_type = SIMPLE
table = people
type = ALL
possible_keys = age, shoesize, height, combinedIndex
key = NULL
key_len = NULL
ref = NULL
rows = 8947017
extra = using where

So it appears that no index is being used when running my query.
I would have expected my combinedIndex to be used for sure.
I am using MariaDB 10.6.19
Where have I gone wrong?

There is the only chance to improve your query. And this is possible only if one of these 3 conditions is highly selective (not more than 5-7% of the rows matches). In this case the index by this column only or the composite index by all 3 columns where this column is a prefix (depends on the average row size) may improve. PS. Maybe the spatial index can be used in this case, but i doubt that this is reasonable.

None of your single-column indexes is selective enough to be worth using. Using a non-selective index means bounding back and forth between the index's BTree and the data BTree.
The composite index is not much better; it still has to work hard to do the filtering.  Also, the single-column index with the same column as the first column in the composite is confusing the Optimizer.  Remove that single-column index; see if it helps.
You could try this also:
select p.*
    FROM (
        SELECT id from people where age > 18
                                and shoesize > 10
                                and height > 150 ) AS p
    JOIN people AS p  USING(id);

I suspect this particular query is just the tip of the iceberg. Since there is a small limit on how many indexes a table can have, I recommend the following: Study actual queries that people use, then build several 2-column indexes. Try to have the first column something that is often tested with =.  Also try to avoid having the first column(s) of two indexes be the same column(s) in the same order.

You could try this also I doubt. The server must do absolutely the same work - it would scan the index for all matched rows PKs, and then it would get the whole rows by matched rows PK values extracted from the index records either implicitly (in original query) or explicitly (in your query). And the server may do this more effecive in the original query.

@Akina - Consider the case where the index's BTree can cached, but the data BTree cannot (due to size). The subquery would scan part (or all) of the smaller index BTree, then reach into the data BTree only a few times.  If the index BTree is small enough to fit into cache (buffer_pool), then the subquery subquery will be fast and the outer part will also be fast because it is only reaching into the data BTree only a few times.
